# How to access Google Compute Engine VM's external ips in a java application

Tags: java, apache-kafka, google-cloud-platform

I am a newbie with GCP.

I have created a Multinode Kafka and Zookeeper cluster in the Google Cloud Platform. I am able to access Kafka binaries and communicate within the cluster by logging into the VM's using `gcloud shell`. Now, I want to access these Kafka brokers in a java application.

Each VM provides Internal-IP and External-IP. When I use the external IP my java application is not able to recognize the IP. Can someone who has experience with google cloud help me access these nodes in my java app.

Here is the java code i am trying to use

```
public class AvroConsumer<T> {

    private static Properties kafkaProps;

    static {
        kafkaProps = new Properties();
        kafkaProps.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        kafkaProps.put("bootstrap.servers", "instance-1:9092,instance-2:9092,instance-3:9092");
        kafkaProps.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        kafkaProps.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ByteArrayDeserializer.class);
        kafkaProps.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "AvroConsumer-GroupOne");
    }

    public void recieveRecord() throws IOException {
        try (KafkaConsumer<String, byte[]> kafkaConsumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(kafkaProps)) {
            kafkaConsumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("jason"));
            while (true) {
                ConsumerRecords<String, byte[]> records = kafkaConsumer.poll(100);
                Schema.Parser parser = new Schema.Parser();
                final Schema schema = parser
                        .parse(AvroProducer.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("syslog.avsc"));
                records.forEach(record -> {
                    SpecificDatumReader<T> datumReader = new SpecificDatumReader<>(schema);
                    ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(record.value());
                    BinaryDecoder binaryDecoder = DecoderFactory.get().binaryDecoder(is, null);
                    try {
                        T log = datumReader.read(null, binaryDecoder);
                        System.out.println("Value: " + log);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Edit1:

I tried configuring the server.properties like below.

```
listeners=INTERNAL://${internal-ip}:19092,EXTERNAL://${external-ip}:9092
listener.security.protocol.map=INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
advertised.listeners=INTERNAL://${internal-ip}:19092,EXTERNAL://${external-ip}:9092
inter.broker.listener.name=INTERNAL
```

It did not work

Comment: Did you open the necessary ports in your [VPC Firewall Rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls)?